# Force HTTPS using Namecheap and Heroku

Tags: heroku, https, ssl-certificate, namecheap

I am using [Heroku Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) and [Namecheap Basic DNS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/782/10/how-do-i-set-my-domain-to-use-namecheap-basicdns).

My problem is that my non-SSL domains are still reachable.

Here is how they map in practice:

```
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|   Entered Domain    |         Result Domain        |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|      name.tld       |    https://www.name.tld/     |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|     www.name.tld    |     http://www.name.tld/     |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
| http://www.name.tld |     http://www.name.tld/     |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|https://www.name.tld |    https://www.name.tld/     |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|   http://name.tld   |    https://www.name.tld/     |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|  https://name.tld   |    error: does not resolve   |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
```

My Heroku Domains settings are:

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|     Domain Name     |     DNS Target    |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|      name.tld       |name1.herokudns.com|
|---------------------|-------------------|
|    www.name.tld     |name2.herokudns.com|
|---------------------|-------------------|
```

My Namecheap Redirect Domain settings are:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|
|     Source URL      |   Destination URL   |
|---------------------|---------------------|
|      name.tld       |https://www.name.tld/|
|---------------------|---------------------|
|    www.name.tld     |https://www.name.tld/|
|---------------------|---------------------|
```

And my Namecheap Host Records settings are:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|        Type         |        Host         |       Value         |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|     CNAME Record    |         www         | name1.herokudns.com.|
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| URL Redirect Record |          @          |https://www.name.tld/|
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

Something to note is I do not put `name2.herokudns.com` into Namecheap because it would conflict, I think.

Comment: Enforcing HTTPS doesn't happen at the DNS level. You need to enforce it at the server or app level. https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls

Comment: Thanks a bunch @ceejayoz I had no idea.

Comment: More in line with this question, do you think there's a way to configure the above settings to fix the url that won't resolve (`https://name.tld`)?

Comment: Chances are Namecheap's redirect solution doesn't support HTTPS. That's pretty common; one of the only registrar-based redirect solutions I've found that *does* support HTTPS is Google's.